# Convert database integer to an associated string in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, web

I have my users table with a column named status. In this column I just store a number, based off their status, 1 - admin, 2 - owner, etc. I know that I can display these values with {{ users->status }}, but only shows the stored number. How can I show the actual name instead of the stored number? And I don't use model here.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an accessor in your `User` model:

```
public function getStatusStringAttribute()
{
    switch ($this->status) {
        case 1:
            return "Admin";
            break;
        case 2:
            return "Owner";
            break;
    }
}
```

and get this attribute like this:

```
{{ $user->statusString }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `enum casting`. Please take a look and see if [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#enum-casting) works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table with user's name role and then join 2 tables.
For example:
You have 1 table named users with column status. You need to create a table for example user_status_name.
id 1 -- name admin,
id 2 -- name user

```
<?php
$users = User::join('user_status_name', 'user_status_name.id', '=', 'users.status')->pluck('name');
?>
```